# Perl would I use fc over uc?

Tags: perl

When would you ever need to use `fc()`, when would `uc()` ever fail?

[Perl fc documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fc.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`fc` is used for case-insensitive comparisons.

```
uc($a) cmp uc($b)    # XXX
lc($a) cmp lc($b)    # XXX
fc($a) cmp fc($b)    # ok
```

An example where this makes a difference:

```
   lc uc fc
-- -- -- --
ss ss SS ss
SS ss SS ss
ß  ß  SS ss
ẞ  ß  ẞ  ss
```

Notice that fc("ß") eq fc("ẞ"), but uc("ß") ne uc("ẞ").

Notice that fc("ß") eq fc("ss"), but lc("ß") ne lc("ss").

---

The table was generated using

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( fc );

use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my $ss = "\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S}";
my $SS = "\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SHARP S}";

printf("   lc uc fc\n");
printf("-- -- -- --\n");
printf("%-2s %-2s %-2s %-2s\n", $_, lc($_), uc($_), fc($_))
   for 'ss', 'SS', $ss, $SS;
```

Comment: but what could you uc(something) and not get SOMETHING?

Comment: Although answer is already accepted. But adding just for better understanding.

As mentioned in http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fc.html

You can think of fc when you are dealing with unicode comparison :D